# How to import sass files using Sass @use

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

I am trying to use new sass module system's feature **@use.** Even after reading in documentation and trying to do same thing, could not figure out how to use it properly. Here is what I have tried:

in **buttons.scss** file I have declared these variables

```
$border-color: black;
$color: white;
$bg: beige;
```

This way, in **main.scss** file I am importing the **buttons.scss** file and trying to use the variables that **buttons.scss** file has .

```
@use "buttons";

$button-color: buttons.$color;
$button-bg: buttons.$bg;
$button-border-color: buttons.$border-color;

.btn{
    color: $button-color;
    border: 1px solid $button-border-color;
    background: $button-bg;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And folder structure looks like this

```
css
sass
 ┣ buttons.scss
 ┗ main.scss
```

And it throws error when compiling `Invalid CSS after \"...-color: buttons\`. I am following this blog [Introducing Sass Modules](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-sass-modules/).

How do I use `@use` properly ?

Comment: you add folder path also.. pls share you folder structure

Comment: Are you using Dart sass? 'Cause only this implemention of SASS currently supports @use.

Comment: Ohh really ! No I was not using Dart sass. I was trying to implement this feature when  I use sass normally with node-sass with npm.

Comment: you try like this @import "buttons";

Comment: @ReSedano , I just have a question .. found that this feature is currentlry just available for Dart Sass 1.23.0 . is this going to be available for for node-sass in the future ?